# sed command to add a line after some pattern

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file (content below)

```
name = [
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```

Now how to i add a command (shell using sed or awk) and i need below output

```
name = [
    "NEW INPUT HERE",
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```

I have tried multiple ways but not able to achieve it. Few of them what i tried
sed '2a'$'\n''   "NEW INPUT HERE", ' filename

I am able to get add it but not giving new line after my input

Answer (score 2):

Some `sed` are finicky, but each of the following should work:

```
$ sed -e '1a\
    "NEW INPUT HERE",
' input-file

$ sed -e $'1a\\\n    "NEW INPUT HERE",\n' input-file # Bashism
```

Comment: Can you share command with pattern after '[' instead of line number ?

Comment: Also How can we add dynamic value or value from variable instead of "NEW INPUT HERE"

Comment: `sed -e '/pattern/a\....`, or `sed -e "/pattern/a\<newline>\"${variable}\",<newline>"`, or `sed -e "/pattern/a"$'\\\n"${variable}",,\n'`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with GNU sed:

```
sed '2i\    "NEW INPUT HERE",'
```

or

```
sed '1a\    "NEW INPUT HERE",'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will just use for the new line whatever indenting you already use for the existing 2nd line:

```
$ awk -v new='"NEW INPUT HERE",' 'NR==2{orig=$0; sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,""); print $0 new; $0=orig} 1' file
name = [
    "NEW INPUT HERE",
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '2{h;s/[[:alpha:]][^"]*/NEW INPUT HERE/};2G' input_file
name = [
    "NEW INPUT HERE",
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```

Comment: Instead of "NEW INPUT HERE" > Do we have a way to pass dynamic value from previous command?

Comment: @Springhills Sure. Lets say the value is in a variable called `var`, you could use `sed "2{h;s/[[:alpha:]][^\"]*/$var/};2G" input_file`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to match the `[` and the next line.

Then capture the newline and leading spaces in group 1.

In the replacement use your text surrounded by double quotes and a backreference to group 1 to keep the indenting the same.

```
sed -E '/\[/{N;/(\n[[:blank:]]+)/{s//\1"NEW INPUT HERE",\1/}}' file
```

Output

```
name = [
    "NEW INPUT HERE",
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2{h;s/\S.*/"NEW INPUT HERE",/p;g}' file
```

On line 2, make a copy of the line, substitute the required string starting where existing text starts indented, print the amended line and reinstate the original line.

Another solution using a regexp for the address line:

```
sed '/name = \[/{n;h;s/\S.*/"NEW INPUT HERE",/p;g}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v str='"NEW INPUT HERE",' '
    /name/{
           print; 
           getline;                                 # get first element (victor)
           le=length($0)-length($1);                # calculate first element ident  
           printf "%*s%s \n%s\n", le, " ", str, $0;
           next
}1' file

name = [
    "NEW INPUT HERE", 
    "victor",
    "linda",
    "harris",
    "sandy"
]
```